# Tab key no longer lists directory contents in zsh

Tags: macos, zsh

<kbd>Tab</kbd> used to run an `ls` locally and in ssh sessions to offer suggestions, but this no longer works. It worked on my old Intel Mac, but now no longer works on my M1 MacBook.

I've tried adding some plugins to get it to work but none of them are working correctly.
Plugin added was zsh-autosuggestions.

Example:
Typing something like `cd`  and then hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> would show a list of the directories under the current one for selection. <kbd>Tab</kbd> would also auto-complete based on history.

How can I get this to work again?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the custom configuration that was added.  On macOS, `zsh` supports tab completion by default.

You can test this easily by making a new user account in the User and Groups preference pane and then `su - shortname` and testing a clean setup.